# External css file not working when using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrapping

I am using bootstrap for my website design but when I use an external css file named mycss.css then it is not working at all.
what shall I do?
Both the file, mycss.css and index.php are in same folder.

[My source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqQAt.png)

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the question.

Comment: Add your `mycss.css` file below all the `css` files.

Comment: Not working. already checked it out.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are Bootstrap components not rendering? Your external reference for it is correct, so that is seemingly not the issue.

Comment: the external css file mycss.css is not working

Comment: Without seeing it's contents there is not much debug we can do from here. If it is in the same directory, as you say, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not the best way to fix your problem, but you can try to add the `!important` declaration to the classes that don't work in your custom.css

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/